# Javascript: Increasing/decreasing number to target

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to count from one preset number to a higher or lower number on input, and show the animation of the change?

There will be an initial amount, let say 100; and when we give it an increased or decreased number, let's say 200, the original 100 will count up animated to 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) like this:

```
var count = 100;
var number = 110;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById('elementID').innerHTML = ++count;

   if (count === number) { clearInterval(interval) }
}, 500);
```

Use `++count` if you want to increase or `--count` if you want to decrease.

### [Working Example](http://jsbin.com/exilas)

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: No, whatever value you specify to `var number = 210;`. It is differnce between `count` and `number` vars. Making `number` larger or lower than `count` decides how much it has to go eg increase number or decrease it.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Let's see and wait if what you understand is what OP is thinking about too :)

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment: Confusion taken care of, see the updated answer please :)

Comment: Sarfraz & @Kevin Thanks, I think I got the general idea on how to tweak it to work the way I need it. Thanks both! This is the general idea: I will have a price on a section and when it receives a new price value, the original price value will increase or decrease depending on the new price old price relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand what you mean, but the count thing is simple:

```
function count() {
   var i; //declare i for use later in the function

   for (i = 100; i <= 200; i++) {
      alert(i);
   }
}
```